# How do i check for memory leaks in firebreath plugin

Tags: c++, firebreath

when i close the browser (iexplore.exe *32) i see zombies of it in Task manager. i suspect memory leak or other bad deinit that prevent the browser from closing.
How do i debug and trace those leaks?
I am using visual studio 2010 on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be a memory leak as such, though it might *also* cause a memory leak if there is something keeping it alive.

Try attaching a debugger to the processes first and see if any of them actually do have your plugin loaded. If so, see if they are locked up on anything. (Look at the different threads, look at the modules tab and see what is loaded, etc).